# How to reset connection between drone and RC for MAVIC Air 2

Tags: troubleshooting, dji-mavic-air-2

My new dji Mavic Air 2 arrived, but it was not connected to the remote control as it is supposed to be connected upon arrival. I then tried connecting it manually following the on-screen instructions of the DJI Fly App, but the Mavic Air 2 doesn't go into the pairing mode when I press the on/off button for 4 seconds or more.

The connection between the App and RC works. The drone is turned on, it does its self-test and briefly beeps. The 4 LEDs are constantly on. Holding down the power button makes it flash slowly, but there is no beep and the LEDs will stop flashing when I release the button.

Is there any other way to reset / pair the drone to the remote control?

Comment: I tried that and it did not work. This all happened after I updated firmware. Any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### In this case there is no way to reset the connection. It is a defective unit. I sent it back and ordered a new one.

Result of chat discussion with @Daniil:

I couldn't connect the drone to the RC nor to a PC/Mac (it never showed up in the DJI Assistant for Mavic nor in the usb device list), and therefore not reset or update the drones firmware. @Daniil and me concluded, the drone is defect. I sent it back to Amazon and ordered a new one.

I also opened a support ticket at DJI, describing the problem. So far I got no response, but hope they use this feedback to fix the bug and improve their QA.

Comment: Thanks for posting this - let me know how the new drone goes

Comment: The new drone works flawlessly! As supposed, it was connected to the RC out of the box. Apparently the first one was indeed a defective unit.

Answer (score 4):

According to page 36 of the [DJI Mavic Air 2 manual](https://dl.djicdn.com/downloads/Mavic_Air_2/20200519/Mavic_Air_2_User_Manual_v1.0_en_.pdf) the aircraft should be linked to the remote controller on arrival.

If not, you should follow these steps:

> 1. Power on the remote controller and the aircraft.
> 2. Launch DJI Fly.
> 3. In camera view, tap (*three dots*)  and select Control and Connect to Aircraft.
> 4. Press and hold the power button of the aircraft for more than four seconds. The aircraft beeps once indicating it is ready to link. The aircraft beeps twice indicating linking is successful. The battery level LEDs of the remote controller will glow solid.

**I think the issue was you didn't try to link it through the *DJI Fly* app.**

Comment: Thanks for your help! I just tried it again – the RC is beeping and looking for the drone. Unfortunately on the drone side nothing happens when I press the power button for more than 4s. I can switch the drone on, cooling fans are audible and the done does it's self test, but when holding the button it won't beep. The battery level LEDs glow solid all the time, but it is not connected to my remote.

Comment: @youngpilot Is your remote control charged and close to the aircraft?

Comment: Yes, it is fully charged and directly next to the drone.

Comment: @youngpilot maybe you can try linking with a different device? Have you followed all the steps here: https://www.heliguy.com/blog/linking-the-remote-controller-dji-mavic-air/

Comment: You mean using another smartphone? The DJI Fly App shows that the RC is connected to the smartphone. Otherwise, I don't have another drone at hand nor another compatible remote. The steps in the link are for the DJI Go 4 App. These steps seem to be different in the DJI Fly app.

Comment: @youngpilot yes, maybe try another smartphone? Have you followed the steps here: https://youtu.be/JXnp3PQiJ6s

Comment: I can try a different smartphone, but don't think this is the issue. The video shows steps for the old Mavic Air 1 - which are different from the Mavic Air 2. The App is structured differently and the drone has no function button. Only the power button.

Comment: @youngpilot you need to release the button when you hear the beep are you doing this?  Another video: https://youtu.be/8lCp8keyf3E

Comment: Thats the problem: there is no beep

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108369/discussion-between-daniil-and-youngpilot).